# How to install ImageMagick for use with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rvm

I had a non-rvm app going and decided to move to RVM. Now I'm noticing paperclip failing as ImageMagick isn't available.

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError: Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.>
```

What's the right way to get ImageMagick installed on RVM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On ubuntu, but this might also work on MacOS.  You def want to compile from source when using ruby.  Here the script I use

*install_imagemagick.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p ~/local
command -v identify > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "${bldgrn}Installing imagemagick into ${txtwht}$HOME/local/imagemagick${txtrst}"
    wget -N --retr-symlinks ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz
    tar -xzvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
    cd ImageMagick-*
    ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/imagemagick
    make
    make install
    cd ..
    rm -rf ImageMagick-*
fi
```

Then I add this to my ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc

```
export PATH=$HOME/local/imagemagick/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/imagemagick/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then you can install your ruby bindings if necessary:

```
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: I love you.  I have a rails install on a shared host, and for some reason rails could not execute the identity/convert in /usr/local/bin, even with exported paths and Paperclip.options.merge!(:command_path => "/usr/local/bin")

this fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 39):

On OS X if you have brew installed, you can simply use the following command:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Comment: The Ubuntu selected suggestion did not work for me in OS X as installing the imagemagick gem afterwards would run into problems. This solution worked flawlessly.

Comment: @Iuhu ok so the obvious question would be: how can you capture such dependency without having it in `Gemfile`? is there any other way than having to have this information in the installation docs or wiki?

Comment: @abbood I haven't tried yet, but maybe doable with a `.gemspec` file?

Answer (score 22):

ImageMagick isn't a gem, it's a normal packet. On debian, the package name is `imagemagick`. You can install it via `apt-get install imagemagick` as root.

Comment: Thanks, I had imagemagick on my machine as it was working before RVM. now that I have my app working with RVM it's not working. Do I need to install ImageMagick in RVM?

Comment: Maybe the paperclip version installed by rvm requires a higher version of imagemagick? Try updating it.

Answer (score 10):

None of the above worked (on Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit)

I had to

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

then

```
gem install rmagick
```

(in Rails 3.1)

Answer (score 0):

For Cygwin, remember to use:

http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-i686-pc-cygwin.tar.gz

instead of:

http://cygwin.com/packages/ImageMagick/

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu, you can install the package using:

`apt-get install imagemagick`